# Scala play coffee not compile javascript in public/javascript/

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, coffeescript

I'm working with Scala play 2.3.8.  I have my coffee script in `myapp/app/assets/javascript/main.coffee` directory.

In my view have the following line of code:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")"></script>
```

My project compiles without errors, but my `main.js` not found in:

```
myapp/public/javascripts/
```

The file is only found in:

```
target/web/public/javascript/
```

Why is this happening?  Do I need to to create the script `main.js` in `myapp/public/javascripts/`?  How do I do this?

Comment: That is correct. I think the file is not supposed to go to public folder. If you access `/assets/javascripts/main.js` (supposing you are using the default asset mapping) in your browser you get a 404?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not supposed to be in your public folder. Autogenerated code (the compiled coffee script) should always be in your target folder.

Accessing it from the browser should be possible.